# Validation doesn't work - CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to add validation on change password function but it doesn't work.

I have added

```
->add('repeat_password', [
                          'equalToPassword' => [
                                                'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                                                    return $value === $context['data']['new_password'];
                                                },
                                                'message' => __("Your password confirm must match with your password.")
                                               ]
                         ]);
```

to `Users` model 
and in my controller

```
$user = $this->Users->get($this->_User['user_id']);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->createEntity($user, ['password' => $this->request->data['repeat_password']]);
           // $verify = (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->check($this->request->data['old_password'], $user->password);
           // debug($verify);
           //if ($verify) {
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success('The password has been changed');
                $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);

            } else {
                $this->Flash->error('Password could not be issued');

            }
           }
        //   else {

           //    $this->Flash->error('Password Do not match');

        //   }
     //   }
    }
```

It saves data without validating. What is the solution ?

Comment: Please post the code for  method `createEntity()`.

Comment: can you print out the value of your `$user`

Answer (score 1):

Without having checked your code thoroughly, my first thought is that CakePHP 3 already provides the built-in validator `compareWith` for this purpose.

Try setting the validation rules as follows:

```
$validator->add('repeat_password', [
    'compareWith' => [
        'rule' => ['compareWith', 'new_password'],
        'message' => __("Your password confirm must match with your password.")

    ]
]);
```

Also, check that both `new_password` and `repeat_password` are set to `true` in the `$_accessible` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public $validate = array(

    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A password is required'
        ),
        'min_length' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),  
            'message' => 'Password must have a mimimum of 6 characters'
        )
    ),

    'password_confirm' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Please confirm your password'
        ),
         'equaltofield' => array(
            'rule' => array('equaltofield','password'),
            'message' => 'Both passwords must match.'
        )
    ),




)
```

please write code in your model more detail please check below link
http://miftyisbored.com/a-complete-login-and-authentication-application-tutorial-for-cakephp-2-3/